# What's the difference between printf and printf_s?

Tags: c, printf

I just want to know the difference and I've already tried search on google.

- printf()
- printf_s()

Answer (score 7):

I learned something new today.  I've never used the `_s` functions and always assumed they were vendor-supplied extensions, but they are actually defined in the language standard under Annex K, "Bounds-checking Interfaces".  With respect to `printf_s`:

> **K.3.5.3.3 The `printf_s` function**
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
> 1 #define _ _STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1_ _ 1
>   #include <stdio.h>
>   int printf_s(const char * restrict format, ...);
> ```
>
> **Runtime-constraints**
> 2 `format` shall not be a null pointer. The **`%n`** specifier<sup>394)</sup> (modified or not by flags, field
> width, or precision) shall not appear in the string pointed to by `format`. Any argument
> to `printf_s` corresponding to a `%s` specifier shall not be a null pointer.
> 3 If there is a runtime-constraint violation, the **`printf_s`** function does not attempt to
> produce further output, and it is unspecified to what extent `printf_s` produced output
> before discovering the runtime-constraint violation.
> **Description**
> 4 The **`printf_s`** function is equivalent to the **`printf`** function except for the explicit
> runtime-constraints listed above.
> **Returns**
> 5 The **`printf_s`** function returns the number of characters transmitted, or a negative
> value if an output error, encoding error, or runtime-constraint violation occurred.
>
> ---
>
> <sup>394) It is not a runtime-constraint violation for the characters **`%n`** to appear in sequence in the string pointed
> at by format when those characters are not a interpreted as a **`%n`** specifier. For example, if the entire
> format string was **`%%n`**.</sup>

<sup>*[C 2011 Online Draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)*</sup>

To summarize, `printf_s` performs additional runtime validation of its arguments not done by `printf`, and will not attempt to continue if any of those runtime validations fail.

The `_s` functions are *optional*, and the compiler is not required to support them.  If they are supported, the macro `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` will be defined to 1, so if you want to use them you'll need to so something like

```
#if __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ == 1
    printf_s( "%s", "This is a test\n" );
#else
    printf( "%s", "This is a test\n" );
#endif
```

Comment: "I ... always assumed they were vendor-supplied extensions" I believe that they *were* vendor-supplied extensions, specifically they were proprietary Microsoft Visual Studio extensions. But they later managed to get them folded into the C standard.